# Ubuntu Disk Size Problem

Tags: 20.04, disk

I have problem, I asked once, but nobody responded and question died. So I need to ask again, and add more details to it. I have my 3 years old computer, which is pretty good (i5 8400, GTX 1070) that have 256 GB (1/4 TB) SSD drive, which I am using as my system drive. I installed Ubuntu on it this summer and everything looked fine. After some time, somewhere around October, I started running out of space (like 50 GB left) I thinked that it's fine, since I installed some games, a lot of programs, etc. But after another month it was getting criticly to like 15 GB left and I started to try to find some way to clean a disk. I used Baobab to look what's taking most space on my disk and I realized, that my user folder is taking only 60 GB (and all of big apps like games are in my home folder). So, I now want to know, where did my disk space go ? Even if a lot of apps were installed outside of my home folder, it would still not take more than 40 GB, or is it ?

Output of df -h : https://pastebin.com/QdQTHgTY

Screenshot from Disks: [image]

Comment: You seem to be using ZFS. Without being an expert, it appears that ZFS assigns a whole lot of storage pools for different system folders (what you see under `rpool/`), which are not really fully used as you can see, but not available for other applications either. I'm not sure that's the optimal file system for a small SSD.

Comment: @Sebastian So is there any way that I can fix this ? Or do I need to reinstall my OS ? (At worst, I can do it, I am planning to change my OS on my next computer in 6 months, but maybe I can do it in Christams time....)

Comment: @nicoebd As an aside, I have just loaded 20.04.1 on to a new PC and my volume table looks the same - as it is on my 18.04.5 installation. I tried fiddling with the partition options and it didn't change anything significantly which addresses your issue - I think it might be processor dependant. I am minded to re-ask your question in the next few days in a slightly different way when I re-load 20.04.1 on my test PC. My, thought is: should the question really address the question as to the best way to exploit Partition 2 on a SSD/NVMe drive. An older PC with SSD/18.04.1 utilises the whole volume

Comment: @User24601 Rest assured, nothing about disk space allocation is processor-dependent. nicoebd: I don't know if there is an easy way to fix this, you might want to read up on ZFS. And on the next installation I would recommend going for ext4 as a filesystem.

Comment: @Sebastian that seems to be the key... the 2 newer PCs are shown as efi and the older one as ext4. Is it possible to format the newer ones as ext4 and what are the consequences? Will this resolve the OPs issue too?

Comment: @User24601 Which "older" and "newer" PC are you talking about? Nothing in the OP's post suggests that. Please don't mix the comments up with your own problem, create a new question for that.

Comment: @Sebastian if you bothered to read my comments you will see what is being referred to which does directly address the OPs point. If you have nothing to add to answer the question, best to keep silent perhaps than try to score cheap points. I already said that I will post a separate, related question.